# How to hide email from shell prompt with starship

Tags: shell, prompt

Currently, my terminal looks like this:

```
~ on ☁️ email@gmail.com took 15s
>
```

I want to hide the email from the view such that the terminal view is just

```
~ took 15s
>
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to fix this issue, first take a look at what is being displayed. For one, there is a `☁️` emoji being displayed next to the email. With this in mind, the Starship configuration documentation (https://starship.rs/config/) can be examined. This is where all of the default formatting within the Starship shell prompt comes from, which means by searching here, we are bound to find the element that is causing trouble.

In order to find the piece of the documentation relevant to the email, you can do a quick page search (CMD + F) for the `☁️` emoji on the page. This is because somewhere in the documentation, there must be a section that formats an email, and an email must have the `☁️` emoji in it. After performing this search, it is possible to see that there are three possible places containing this emoji:

1. AWS
2. Google Cloud
3. OpenStack

**Solution/TLDR**

Try disabling each of these formatters until the email is gone. In my case, Google Cloud was the one causing the issue. To disable a certain element in Starship go to your starship.toml file (should be found at `~/.config/starship.toml`) and set the disabled parameter to true like this:

```
[gcloud]
disabled = true
```

Replace `[gcloud]` with one of the three services mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Just to add, my issue was also related to the `[gcloud]`. Even though I did not set it in my configuration file, it was active because I had my Google Cloud CLI setup.